# Cannot find peculiar rho symbol and special parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I googled a lot but I did not manage to reproduce:

- this rho symbol
  [image: special rho font] and
- this special parenthesis [image: special parenthesis].

Thanks in Advance,

Mirko

Comment: For the first, perhaps `$\varrho$`

Comment: `\Lbag` of `stmaryrd` package.

Comment: `Gfs Bodoni` has a varrho close to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is the proper way to search for these.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\varrho \Lbag$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a composite glyph to better capture the odd `\varrho`, given by an overlay of `\varsigma` and a stretched `o`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$\varsigma \varrho \Lbag 
\stackengine{1.45pt}{\varsigma}{\hstretch{1.25}{\mkern.3mu\scriptstyle o}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks for the link! The parenthesis is right, but I think that the character of the image is different from \varrho. If you look it is slightly different.

Comment: @Briomkez I attributed that to the font designer's choice, though I have not found another font that presents it quite that way.  Kind of cross between a `\varrho` and a `\zeta`.

Comment: @Briomkez Please see my edit.